# Importing a .PFX Certificate in Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, automation, ssl-certificate

I used the script Register-PnPAzureADApp for creating an Azure APP Registration with a .PFx Certificate and a password on my local computer.
Then I want to upload it to my Azure environment to an Auotmation Account, but when I try to upload the certificate. I get an error message.

I don't know why I'm getting this error message. My password is definitly correct.

Here is the code for the creation so far and the error message:

```
$tenant ="{tenant}"
$clientFile= "PNP-PowerShell-Client3.txt"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@$$w0rd' -AsPlainText -Force
 $reg =Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName "IAS-AutomationApp3" -Tenant 
$tenant".onmicrosoft.com" -Password $password -Interactive
$reg."AzureAppId/ClientId" | Out-File $clientFile -Force
```

I hope you can help.

Matthias

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnwCo.png)